# Select range A1 to the lastrow in column A

Tags: excel, select, range, vba

I'm new to VBA so sorry if this is an elementary question. I am trying to select a range from A1 down to the last cell in column A using the Dim LastRow.
My code as follows.

```
Sub

Dim sht As Worksheet

Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

LastRow = sht.range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

'everything works properly up to this point

range(A,LastRow").Select

End Sub
```

I know the problem is with that last line of code... I just don't know how to properly refer to a range variable to select it. 
Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways. If you are using CurrentRegion you scarcely need the variable (but this only detects contiguous blocks of data). And don't use Select - usually unecessary and slows your code down.

```
Sub x()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

'everything works properly up to this point

sht.Range("A1", sht.Range("A" & LastRow)).Select
'sht.Range("A1").Resize(LastRow).Select
'sht.Range("A1", sht.Cells(LastRow, 1)).Select
'sht.Range("A1", sht.Cells(LastRow, "A")).Select
'sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 1).Select ' this one doesn't need LastRow

End Sub
```